# Understanding std::apply inside std::visit

Tags: c++, c++17

https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/e3e93e307456a388a84a6e0d96f9adb240f5918d/apps/fxlab/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp#L93

```
std::visit([id](auto &&stack) {
    std::function<void(decltype(stack.getType()), decltype(stack.getType()))> f;
    int i = 0;
    std::apply([id, &f, &i](auto &&... args) mutable {
        ((f = (i++ == id) ?
              args.template buildDefaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>() : f), ...);
    }, EffectsTuple);
    stack.addEffect(std::move(f));
}, enginePtr->functionList);
```

std::visit applies the lambda to the vector `functionList`. The lambda, applies the lambda inside of it to the `EffectsTuple`.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding

```
((f = (i++ == id) ?
              args.template buildDefaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>() : f), ...);
```

What does the outer most `()` does? what is the second argument `...`? What does `args.template` mean?

Comment: `()` does what it does most of the time: make a function call. `...` designates a fold expression. `args.template` invokes a template member of `args`. Perhaps if you asked one question per stackoverflow.com question it might be meaningful to answer with a capsule summary of the relevant C++17 features, but for a bunch of questions about basic C++17 functionality, the best common answer would be to refer you to a recent textbook covering advance template usage, and C++17 features.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The outer `()` aren't a function call. They are part of the fold expression syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((f = (i++ == id) ?
          args.template buildDefaultEffect<defaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>() : f), ...);
```

this is a comma-fold execute pack expansion.  It is an awkard way to iterate over non-uniform typed elements in a tuple.

If you could iterate over a pack of non-uniform elements:

```
int i=0;
for...(auto& arg:args...){
  if (i!=id){
    ++i;
    continue;
  }
  f=arg.template buildDefaultEffect<defaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>();
  break;
}
```

this is the code they'd like to write.  But they cannot.

So they use comma-fold execute to generate something equivalent to the body of the loop above for each arg in args.

And in the "do nothing" bodies they do `f=f`.

Myself I'd do:

```
((i++ == id) ?
          f=args.template buildDefaultEffect<defaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>() : nullptr), ...);
```

which is both clearer and more efficient.

Alternatively, `foreach_arg` is a useful alternative to write.  Or making a n-sized array of function pointers, each one doing a loop body, and only running one.

Comment: `cond ? f = got_stdFunction() : nullptr` might still create an empty `std::function`, immediate lambda `[&](){ if (i++ == id) { f = args.template buildDefaultEffect<defaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>();} }(), ...)` seems even better.

Comment: @jarod42 empty std functions are pretty trivial.  I'd bet they optimize to zilch.

Comment: With type-erasure type, I won't bet ;) (self assignment should also be easy to optimize btw IMO). For readability point, the `nullptr` trick only works for `std::function` (and other "nullable" types), lambda can be transposed to other types :)

Comment: and in above case, I might even create `std::function` array, and just do `f = funcs[id];`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Naw, `function( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;` -- it does no allocation when constructed from `nullptr`.  The null `std::function` is different than the non-null one.

Comment: why the `break`? Could somebody explain how the fold expression introduces a `break`?

Comment: @guer it does not; it just repeatedly does `f=f`.  This is a "do nothing" operation.  Before I treated it as "continue", after "break".  I said "if they could iterate, here is what they would write" not "the fold expression does these things".

Answer (score 2):

> what is the second argument ...?

`(foo(args), ...)` is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), using comma operator, equivalent to `(foo(arg0), foo(arg1), ..,  foo(argn))`

> What does args.template mean?

`template` is used to disambiguate meaning of `<` for dependent type:

without that, it would be parsed as

`(args.buildDefaultEffect < decltype(stack.getType())) > ()`.

see [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: But there are no args in `((f = (i++ == id) ?
              args.template buildDefaultEffect<decltype(stack.getType())>() : f), ...);`. How does it knows how much times to apply?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: `args` itself is a pack in that expression.

Answer (score 2):

That `...` is a right fold over the comma operator. What that code essentially does is call the `buildDefaultEffect` function for the `args` variable with the requested id, assigns the return value to `f` and then adds `f` to the stack with `stack.addEffect`.

Basically that code expands to something like

```cpp
(f = f, f = f, /*i == id*/ f = args.buildDefaultEffect(stack.getType()), f = f, f = f);
stack.addEffect(f);
```

Comment: what is the `()` structure that you made? `(f=f, f=f, ...)`. What the parenthesis mean?